# how to place a listview inside a SingleChildScrollView but prevent them from scrolling separately?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a widget tree like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView
   Column
     Container
       ListView(or GridView)
```

the problem is that when my widget tree is like above, it gives me error of

> NEEDS PAINT

so I change my widget tree like this:

```
Column
     Container
       ListView(or GridView)
```

but in this situation the ListView or GridView part scrolls separately, and I want the whole widget tree to scroll. how do you think I can achieve it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As suggested by other answers, you can do that by setting `shrinkWrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, but building a shrinkwrapped listview is more expensive than building a normal listview, I think it will be a good idea to use a map() on the list.

```
Column(
  children: itemList.map((item) {
       return Text(item);
    }).toList()
),
```

Answer (score 173):

You could use your first widget-tree and apply the following changes:

1. In every `ListView` and `GridView` set `shrinkWrap: true`. This fixes the error message you were getting.
2. In every `ListView` and `GridView` set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`. This disables the scroll on them and new you can only scroll on the `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: please also note that by making `shrinkWrap: true` makes the `ListView` or `GridView` more expensive to build. see more: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

Answer (score 52):

For me, setting primary to false and shrinkWrap to true worked.

```
ListView(
   primary: false,
   shrinkWrap: true,
),
```

Comment: Agree "shrinkwrap:true" becomes necessry when you are inside singlechilscrollview

Comment: This is what worked for me. Also my inner list has an infinite scroll in itself so probably the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics of other responses woudn't fit it.

Answer (score 35):

**Why it is happening?**

It happens because `Column` and `ListView` both take the entire space of screen individually which is there default behavior.

**How to solve the problem?**

To solve the above problem we have to disable scrolling of Listview, This can be possible by `shrinkWrap` and `physics` property

**shrinkWrap:true**  - It forces ListView to take only the required space, not the entire screen.

**physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()** - It disables scrolling functionality of ListView, which means now we have only SingleChildScrollView who provide the scrolling functionality.

**Code:**

```
SingleChildScrollView
   Column
     Container
        ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                //...
                )
```

**Note:** Above `ListView` behaviour will be also applied for `GridView`.

Comment: This works fine but it prevents listview builder to create item widgets on demand. All items are created at once. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @RadhikaGokani: Could you please create a new question and paste it here, so that I can understand in detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467737/listview-builder-inside-singlechildscrollview-prevents-widget-creation-on-demand  @JiteshMohite

Comment: Its not a solution. It will crop the nested widget. And you need it to take up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 30):

Set `primary` to `false` in your `ListView`.

```
ListView(
   primary: false,
),
```

That should prevent it from scrolling separately.

Answer (score 18):

I am using nested `Listviews` and this helped me. Add these lines in all of your `ListviewBuilders`

```
ListView(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   primary: false,
),
```

Comment: its not a good idea to shrinkwrap all your listviews. ListView.builder builds it children lazily meaning that it will only build if the widget is on the user's screen. (Ex: when the user scrolls down) shrinkwrapping the listview will make the listviewbuilder build all its children all at once.

Answer (score 2):

using this inside listview works fine for me.

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: Its not a solution. It will crop the nested widget. And you need it to take up the rest of the space

Answer (score 1):

I used the combination of all three (`primary: false, shrinkWrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`) and it just worked:

```
   SingleChildScrollView(

      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: ListView.builder(primary: false, shrinkWrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), itemCount: movies.length ,itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Movie movie = movies[index];
              return Container(
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  key: ValueKey(movie.title),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(movie.title),
                    subtitle: Text(movie.duration),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                      color: movies[index].isFav ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<MovieProvider>().updateFav(!movies[index].isFav, movie);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work like a charm.

```
Column(
children: itemList.map((item) {
   return Text(item);
}).toList(),
),
```