# Adding listview inside the middle of my layout flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to display my listview in between other items in the page. My basic flow is like so right now:

```
AppBar Body:
-Image
-Title
-IntroText
-NEED LIST VIEW HERE
```

Here is my Widget and Layout following:

```
ListView _buildSectionList(List<Sections> sections, context) {
  print(sections.length);
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: sections.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            leading: Text(index.toString()),
            title: new Text(
              (sections[index].content),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          new Divider(
            height: 12.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

If I insert just that _buildSectionList into the body: it will display data just fine.

However, when I add it to my Layout below, I get errors (below layout):

```
children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 15.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            title.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black54),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(landingpagecontent, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      _buildSectionList(sections,context),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                            child: InkWell(
                                child: Text("Learn More >",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                onTap: () async {
                                  var url = weblink;
                                  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                    await launch(url, forceWebView: false);
                                  } else {
                                    throw 'Could not launch $url';
                                  }
                                }),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
```

*I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#4d43f relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#18160 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#4486e relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#b4572 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#87d08 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#8fa89 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#b9ffd relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#f3831 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#fe472 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#6b201 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#da0f9 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#68715 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b7790 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#eb17f relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (29498): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#eb17f relayoutBoundary=up1*

I've tried the Expanded() widget with no results there either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a try with it:

**Demo:**

[image: Demo ListView]

**Code:**

```
Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text("Image"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text("Text"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: _buildListView(),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.cyanAccent,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text("Bottom 1"),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text("Bottom 2"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 1000,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Center(child: Text("Item ${index + 1}")),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Divider(
          height: 1,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is close, however, I'd like my whole view to scroll. I was able to achieve this with the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134656/350421. I do like this approach however for another use!

Comment: ListView must be inside for size box or container, it needs a particular size. then only it renders. Try to wrap in Expanded for  Container.