# Flutter: Container above ListView scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I want to display a `Container` with `Text` followed by a `ListView` of categories. In my current code, it works out except that I wasn't able to figure out, how to make the `Text` and `Container` scrollable as well (so it moves upside away out of the frame).

It looks currently like this:

[image: 1]

The blue container is static and stays at its location while the red `ListView` is perfectly fine scrollable.

Current Code:

```
      body: Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 10),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: const Text("Browse through the individual categories...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Category(),
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

I tried to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499302/flutter-container-listview-scrollable).

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 30),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: const Text("Browse through the individual categories...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Category(),
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I get the following errors:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
>
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#12630 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: Try wrapping your parent widget in Expanded() as I see you have already added shrinkWrap: true

Comment: Do you want the text to be scrollable like it's a child of the listview or make it go out of the view when scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines in your listview

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

You can skip the Expanded widget for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just removed `SingleChildScrollView` widget it will work.

Comment: It won't make the text scrollable.

Comment: I already tried. its work

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with `SingleChildScrollView` widget and then add `physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `ListView` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Simply
by adding **physics** property to the ListView widget and determine it by
**BouncingScrollPhysics** as follow:

ListView(
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
children:[
Widget1,
Widget2,
]
)