# Scroll the screen and listview together, NOT seperately

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, listview

I already looked at these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131101/how-to-place-a-listview-inside-a-singlechildscrollview-but-prevent-them-from-scr/56137112) but they are not working for me. I want LatestNewsList widget and the whole screen scroll together and not seperately.This is the code for the screen:

```
class Search extends StatelessWidget {
  final tab = new TabBar(tabs: <Tab>[
    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
  ]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = LatestNewsProvider.of(context);

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 6,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  // right: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  top: 20,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 32,
                      height: 32,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    SearchBar(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                    labelColor: Colors.blue,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: "Latest",
                      ),
                      Tab(text: "programming"),
                      Tab(text: "general"),
                      Tab(text: "sports"),
                      Tab(text: "academia"),
                      Tab(text: "politics"),
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                //Add this to give height
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: TabBarView(children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.fetchLatestNews();
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.newsStream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.newsStream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.c1Fetch('programming');
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.c1Stream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.c1Stream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.c2Fetch('general');
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.c2Stream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.c2Stream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.c3Fetch('sports');
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.c3Stream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.c3Stream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.c4Fetch('academia');
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.c4Stream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.c4Stream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.searchedListBuilderStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return NewsListBuilder(snapshot);
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('No results found');
                          }
                          bloc.c5Fetch('politics');
                          return Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              HorizontalSearchList(bloc, bloc.c5Stream),
                              LatestNewsList(bloc, bloc.c5Stream, 'Search'),
                            ],
                          ));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

LatestNewsList widget has a widget inside it and that widget has this code which is responsible for the listview building:

```
class NewsListBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final snapshot;

  NewsListBuilder(this.snapshot);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return NewsListBuilderItems(snapshot, index);
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I can not scroll further:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use slivers for more complex scroll pages like yours. Read more on them here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers

I can provide you a simplified example of what I suppose you wanted to do (hope I understood you correctly):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Search(),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Make sure to set the correct length
    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Container(height: 40, color: Colors.grey), // this can be the search bar
            bottom: TabBar(
              indicatorWeight: 3,
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(text: "programming"),
                Tab(text: "general"),
                Tab(text: "sports"),
                Tab(text: "academia"),
                Tab(text: "politics"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          /// here you put all your pages

          // Example of one page
          // You will need to wrap this in StreamBuilder as you do in the
          // original code
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.red.shade200,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works somehow but not completely. where u commented          /// here you put all your tabs your pages
when I do that the listview disappears

Comment: @Benyamin, `PageView` in this case works similarly to `TabBarView` in your post. You can swipe sideways (or click on the tabs) to navigate between the pages. You need to add a CustomScrollView page for each of your categories (programming, general, sports, etc.). These pages must be wrapped in `StreamBuilder`s as you do in the original code.

Comment: how can I add the avatar and search bar at the top of the tab bar?

Comment: you used bottom but I don't find anything for my purpose. I tried actions but it does not work as I want

Comment: @Benyamin, You can put it into one column with the TabBar at the `bottom`. I'll update the answer

Comment: PageView does not swipe as u said. I try but it does not swipe

Comment: That's weird, does clicking on the tabs work?

Comment: The argument type 'Column' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?' it gives this error when I added the column

Comment: and also when I change by clicking it says  ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views

Comment: Try wrapping the `Column` in a container (and specify the height). You should refer to the documentation of the sliverappbar for that: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: The argument type 'Container' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

Comment: I didn't know that the `bottom` parameter requires a specific widget, sorry. You can still use `title` instead. I'll update the answer when I figure out the other problems

Comment: I almost got what I wanted with your answer, thanks!

Comment: @Benyamin  Just fixed it. Turns out I could use `TabBarView` instead of trying to combine `TabView` with `PageView`.

Comment: when I scroll it hides the avatar and the search bar but does not hide the horizontal list. can you help me with that too?