# Flutter: Short list inside SingleChildScrollView on Scaffold Body

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have `SingleChildScrollView` with short `ListView` inside `Scaffold`. As You see on video, `SingleChildScrollView` do not fill whole body of `Scaffold`. How to fix it?
[image]

```dart
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
        child:
            // return
            ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please add your full code with scaffold code please

Comment: Just added full code

Comment: Because the list is short as you said. Add more items it will fill the whole screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to place a listview inside a SingleChildScrollView but prevent them from scrolling separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131101/how-to-place-a-listview-inside-a-singlechildscrollview-but-prevent-them-from-scr)

Comment: No. Linked question talk about ScrollView too, but case is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer as easier than I expect. I try every answer from this thread, but none work as I expect. After a lot of tries I solve this. Screen is still scrollable, but if I pull list down, items do not hide under half of screen like on question post.

**Just `ListView`, without param `shrinkWrap: true` and without wrapping with `SingleChildScrollView`**

Full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// !!! Just `ListView`, without param `shrinkWrap: true` and without wrapping with `SingleChildScrollView`
   return  ListView(children: [
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
SingleChildScrollView
   Column
     Container
        ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                //...
                )
```

- Make list view scroll disabled and `shrinkWrap` true that will help to expand list size based on content

Answer (score 0):

This is the default physics of SingleChildScrollView and if you want to prevent this you can change `physics` to `ClampingScrollPhysics`.and also change Listview to Column or if you want to use Listview, disable it's physics by `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          child:
              // return
              Column(children: [
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text("TEST"),
              subtitle: Text("________"),
            )
          ]))
```

**Second** way is remove SingleChildScrollView and listView's shrinkWrap property and just use listView's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the ScrollBar
and that shrinkWrap property

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: [
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      ),
      const ListTile(
        title: Text("TEST"),
        subtitle: Text("________"),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each item is taking certain height in the listview and the number of item heights can fill the whole screen.
So if you just want to fill the whole body then
Wrap Listview in Container and give whole height of the screen:

```
Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: ListView(....)
)
```